# Hide a <div> with jQuery without using ID or class

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html

I want to hide the following `<div>` in my site pages, but this `<div>` is changing its position dynamically, so I cannot use the code `$("div:eq(0)").hide();`

```
<div style="background: #ebebeb; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
border-left: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 5px; font-size: 12px; position: fixed; right: 3%; 
bottom: 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px; border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;">
Powered by <a href="http://bizmate.in">Bizmate</a></div>
```

Any suggestions on how can I hide that element?

Comment: why cant you assign a class or id to it?

Comment: the <div> is generated by the hosting company, and don't have any id or class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you really should not put all of those styles inline. It clutters your html, and is poor design since you are mixing styling and layout. It would be better to take it out, use css selectors and wrap it in `<style></style>` tags; to that end you should also add a class to the `<div>` to make these selections easier to carry out and more maintainable.

That being said, the following function using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) will do what you want...

```
$("div").filter( function() { 
    return $(this).find("a[href^='http://bizmate.in']").length > 0;
}).hide();
```

Comment: Of course the selector could be improved if you posted your full html, and right now has to assume that such a `<div>` isn't duplicated

Comment: [**Demo of code above**](http://jsfiddle.net/cQUvs/2/), [**Demo of more improved code**](http://jsfiddle.net/cQUvs/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
$('div[style*=background: #ebebeb; [...]').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('div a[href="http://bizmate.in"]').parent().hide();` should work.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/C4pYy/

Answer (score 1):

Why not add an id and then use `$('div#myId').hide()` ?

```
<div id="myId" style="background: #ebebeb; [...]">[...]</div>
```

Comment: THe <div> is generated by the hosting company, so only no ID or CLASS I can't assign, any way I removed, Thanks @mbinette

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("a[href='http://bizmate.in']",  $("#container")).closest('div').hide();
```

Assume in the parent elements of given html, you can find one with id="container", this will ensure the right  is found with that container rather than else where since a link like that is pretty common.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to assign an ID to it, and if you can't, why not?

Here's code for hiding it anyways:

**JSfiddle-example**

Code for hiding with id, without id, and from what your link content is:

http://jsfiddle.net/9eLAJ/3/